# Unable to Record jmeter Script for andriod app

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I'm attempting to use jmeter to run load testing on one of my client's mobile apps. In order for my Android to record the jmeter script, I must send the manual proxy to it first.

My issue arises when I switch from none to manual proxy with every legitimate system IP and port number. I'm having issues since I have WiFi but no internet.

1. Set the jmeter recording template
2. I also connected my LAP and MOBILE to the same network.
3. Jmeter RootCA certification was installed on my phone.
4. Configure the IP address and port according to the jmeter.
5. An internet connection fault has me here. "Connect to WiFi without Internet"

**Kindly find a solution for this.**

Answer (score 0):

1. JMeter needs to be able to access the Internet in order to be able to act as an Internet proxy. So if you're behind a corporate proxy server you need to inform JMeter about it: [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)
2. You need to amend your application [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config), otherwise the app won't trust JMeter's certificate and HTTPS requests will be failing: [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354685999889-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording)